# Formula to calculate the best overall score/review/etc from data in PHP

Tags: php, logic, formula

I'm having trouble wording my problem to search for it, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

I have multiple scores given out of 5 for a series of objects.

How can I find which object has the best overall rating? A similar formula to Amazon's reviews or Reddit's best comments (probably a lot more basic?), so not necessarily finding the highest average score but incorporating the number of reviews given to get the "best".

Any ideas?

Comment: are you asking for an MYSQL query??

Comment: so you want the one that has the maximum value with the minimal variance.

Comment: Bert- No, PHP if possible. imm- That sounds like what I want! Ordered like that. I will have another search now you've mentioned that term

Comment: You want the highest score average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a classical application of the Friedman test: "n wine judges each rate k different wines. Are any wines ranked consistently higher or lower than the others?" Friedman test is implemented in many statistical packages, e.g., in R: friedman.test.

Friedman test will return the p-value. If the p-value is not siginificant there is no reason to assume that some of the objects are consistently ranked higher than other ones. If the p-value is significant, then you know that some objects have been ranked higher than others but you still do not know which ones. Hence, appropriate post-hoc multiple comparisons tests should be performed.

A number of different post-hoc tests can be performed, see e.g., for R code of an example post-hoc analysis http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/